# Getting “no rule to make target” error while trying to run OpenCV code

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to run example code from https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html. I use Ubuntu 16. I have OpenCV installed in `/home/marcin/opencv/` directory. I use `CMakeLists.txt` file like in example, with addition of line

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

I run in terminal

```
cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/marcin/opencv/build
```

and I get positive output. But when I try to run make command I get:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/marcin/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.0.1',
needed by 'DisplayImage'.  Stop.  
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all' failed  
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: Do you have the file, mentioned in the error message? `/home/marcin/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.0.1`. You say that you have OpenCV **installed** in `/home/marcin/opencv/`, but specify as `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` another directory `/home/marcin/opencv/build`, which probably contained OpenCV which is just *built*. So, do you actually have **installed** OpenCV or just **built** one? (For install the project, `make install` is usually performed). And which **actual directory** contains your OpenCV installation?

Comment: @Tsyvarev  
I have don't have file `libopencv_core.so.4.0.1`, but I found `libopencv_core.so.4.0` . I used `make install` if I remember correctly. I used folder `opencv\build` because without it I got error that it needs some file that I found in this folder. What files and folders should I have in properly installed OpenCV folder?

Comment: "... because without it I got error that it needs some file that I found in this folder." - Do you mean file `OpenCVConfig.cmake`? If you correctly install OpenCV, then the file should belong to that installation. The file, located in the build directory, describes the files in that directory. In any case, file `OpenCVConfig.cmake` should describe files which actually exist, the error probably means, that your OpenCV installation is broken. Try to rebuild/reinstall. And again, what is the **actual install directory**, `/home/marcin/opencv` or `/home/marcin/opencv/build` one?

Comment: @Tsyvarev  Yes, I meant `OpenCVConfig.cmake`, sorry. I don't know, maybe I installed in folder build by accident, but don't know how to check the actual install directory. I'll try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tsyvarev suggestet, I reinstalled the library one more time. It seems like it was broken.